# Confusion about relativity of simultaneity

Tags: special-relativity

I am an engineer currently doing some self-study of physics in my spare time.

While learning about the relativity of simultaneity I have come across 2 different example problems that seem to give contradictory results. Both examples deal with an observer on a moving train and a second observer stationary on the platform.

[Example 1](https://www1.phys.vt.edu/%7Etakeuchi/relativity/notes/lightbulb.gif) has a light source at the center of the train

[Example 2](https://slideplayer.com/slide/13197221/79/images/3/Breakdown+of+Simultaneity+Example.jpg) essentially has 2 light sources, as both ends of the train are struck with lightning bolts at t=0

The solutions given for these problems, in the reference frame of the observer on the train, seem to be contradictory. In example 1, the light reaches both ends of the train at the same time, where as in example 2, the 2 lightning flashes do not reach the center of the train at the same time.

How is this not contradictory? In both examples, light in the reference frame of the observer on the train has to move L/2 and has speed c. What am I missing here?

In my mind, if you place mirrors on the ends of the train car and you run the scenario for twice as long, then example 1 becomes example 2, with the light pulses being reflected back to the middle of the train.

Any help understanding this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marco already answered, but let me rephrase it in light of the examples.

In example 1 the simultaneity of light reaching both ends of the train is with respect to observer at rest with the train (called Marvis in example 2). In particular, they are not simultaneous with respect to observer at the ground (called Stanley in example 2)

In example 2, the lightening bolts strike ends of the train simultaneously with respect to Stanley and thus they will not be simultaneous with respect to Marvis. In example 1 this was the other way around, so the two examples are different. And since the two lighting bolts did not strike the ends of the train with respect to Marvis at the same time, they will also not arrive to the center at the same time, even thought this statement of yours

> In both examples, light in the reference frame of the observer on the train has to move L/2 and has speed c

is correct.

Comment: would this still hold if instead of lighting strikes, there were 2 flash bulbs at each end of the train car, and the side of the train car was missing/ fully open to the air?

According to my understanding, in the reference frame of the platform observer, the flashes would still reach Stanley at the same time, and would not reach Mavis at the same time (according to Stanley's POV).

But in the reference frame of the train, would it not be the opposite? Mavis should see the flashes at the same time, but they would reach Stanley at different times (according to Mavis' POV)?

Comment: @CuriousEngineer If two light flashes reach some place at the same time, they do so in all reference frames. Two events that happen at the same place and different times in some reference frame, will not be simultaneous in any reference frame. What is relative is whether the two light pulses start to move from end of the train simultaneously or not. They do so from Stanley's POV, they do not from Marvis. Both of them agree in what order do these flashes reach Stanley. Special theory of relativity preserves causality, i.e. the order of events that can influence each other is absolute.

Answer (score 0):

When you say that in example 2 both ends of the train are struck at t=0, if t is the time on the train then the flashes will reach the centre of the train at the same time- however, if t is the time on the platform, they won't, because the times at either end of the train, in the train's frame of reference, are out of synch with the time of clocks on the platform.

To unpack this a bit more...

If the light from each strike meets at the centre of the train, then from the point of view of the people on the train, the two ends must have been struck at the same time, as both flashes have travelled L/2 in their frame.

However, from the perspective of the people on the platform, the centre of the train is moving forward, so the light from the front strike has travelled less that L/2 to reach the centre, while the light from the rear struck has travelled more than L/2. The only way that can happen is if the rear strike was earlier than the front one.

So, imagine that it is 12 O'clock train time when each end of the train is struck, and that there are clocks all along the platform. An observer at the front of the train, looking out, would see that the clock next to them on the platform was showing just after 12 O'clock, while an observer at the rear of the train would see that the clock next to them on the platform was showing just before 12 O'clock. The observers on the train would conclude that the clocks on the platform  were out of synch. Observers on the platform would believe that their own clocks were in synch, and that the clocks on the train were out.

Comment: thank you for your response, but I am still a bit confused. My understanding of the situation is that each observer would see the events as simultaneous in their own reference frame, and the other observer would see them as non-simultaneous. 

I guess I'm asking, if Paul sees the 2 flashes reaching Mavis at different times in his POV, is it required that Mavis "see" the same result in her POV, but have different reasons for believing so? Ie, would Mavis see the pulses reach her at different times, and reach Paul at the same time in her POV?

Comment: No, each observer cannot see the events as simultaneous- either one does, or the other does. The two events cannot be simultaneous in both frames- that is the whole point of it. Either the events happen simultaneously in the frame of the train, in which case they are not simultaneous in the frame of the platform, or they happen simultaneous on the frame of the platform, in which case they are not simultaneous in the frame of the train.

Comment: Consider an analogy with faulty spirit levels. Imagine Paul's level is off to the right, while Mavis' level is off to the left. Paul uses his level to make two marks on a wall- according to him they are level, but to Mavis they are not. Likewise Mavis can make two marks on the wall with her level- according to her, the marks are level but to Paul they are not.

Comment: In relativity, planes of simultaneity are analogous to the spirit levels. Just as you can use a spirit level to mark lines of constant height, imagine a time-spirit-level which gives you a constant time everywhere. If the two flashes happen at a constant time level according to Mavis' time-spirit-level, then according to Paul, whose time-spirit-level is tilted compared with the level Mavis has used, the two flashes happen at different times.